# Optimal way to populate a large number of textboxes in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

I'm currently creating a WPF application using MVVM. I have a large number of textboxes in a window (about 20) that need to be bound to specific elements in a list and need to be populated all at once. Normally I'd push them into an array and populate them that way but I can't do so without breaking the MVVM model. Is there a quick and efficient way I can do this while still adhering to MVVM?

Comment: Can you give some more detail, what do you want to put in textboxes?

Comment: What's wrong with just binding them to the elements in your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why strictly this would break MVVM, if instead of using an Array you used a List, put it in your ViewModel and then use indexed binding to bind to specific elements.

Something like:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding MyViewModelList[0]}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding MyViewModelList[1]}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding MyViewModelList[2]}">
</StackPanel>
```

or if you want something more dynamic, instead of List, put an ObservableCollection in your VM, and bind to it in an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyViewModelObsCol}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>                 
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Syntax might not be 100% as I don't have an IDE to test, but something along these lines might be what you're after.

Comment: True. I was hoping for a way to incrementally bind them VS. just binding them each one by one to the elements.

Answer (score 5):

You could bind your list to an `ItemsControl` and change it's item template to be a `TextBox`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource={Binding aList}>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to populate textbox on the bases of selection in list box  [try this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970558.aspx)
Another option is creating a COllection view source which i don't think you will require here